# in the background execute cannot back to correct Activity page

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

in the background execute cannot back to the correct Activity page.

I have got the fid values, if I get a notification in the app then I click the notification, I can go to the correct Activity page, but when I get a notification in the background execute when I click the notification, it's always going to MainActivity.

Where has a problem?

this is code

```
public class MyFirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    private String getID,fid;
    private Intent intent;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        sessionManager.checkLogin();
        HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
        getID = user.get(sessionManager.USERID);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.i("MyFirebaseService","title "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            Log.i("MyFirebaseService","body "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            if(data.get("fid") != null){
                fid = data.get("fid").toString();
            }
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), fid);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody, String fid) {
            if(fid != null){
                intent = new Intent(this, NewNotificationPostInfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, fid);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }else{
                intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        String channelId = "channelID";

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.luvtas_au2);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.luvtas_au3)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setGroup(channelId)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.i("MyFirebaseService","token "+s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the notification code like it.

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
long notificatioId = System.currentTimeMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class); // Here pass your activity where you want to redirect.

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) (Math.random() * 100), intent, 0);

int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    currentapiVersion = R.mipmap.ic_notification_lolipop;
} else{
    currentapiVersion = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
}

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(currentapiVersion)
        .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify((int) notificatioId, notificationBuilder.build());   }
```

Comment: same.... still will go to welcomeActivity then transfer to MainActivity....  I hope, when click the notification on background execute, it can go to NewNotificationPostInfoActivity

Comment: Refer to the Official Documentation.   https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation